# Python Join String to Produce Combinations For All Words in String

Tags: string, python-3.x, join, combinations

If my string is this: `'this is a string'`, how can I produce all possible combinations by joining each word with its neighboring word?

What this output would look like:

```
this is a string
thisis a string
thisisa string
thisisastring
thisis astring
this isa string
this isastring
this is astring
```

What I have tried:

```
s = 'this is a string'.split()    
for i, l in enumerate(s):
        ''.join(s[0:i])+' '.join(s[i:])
```

This produces:

```
'this is a string'
'thisis a string'
'thisisa string'
'thisisastring'
```

I realize I need to change the `s[0:i]` part because it's statically anchored at 0 but I don't know how to move to the next word `is` while still including `this` in the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use [itertools.product()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
import itertools

s = 'this is a string'

words = s.split()
for t in itertools.product(range(len('01')), repeat=len(words)-1):
    print(''.join([words[i]+t[i]*' ' for i in range(len(t))])+words[-1])
```

Comment: Please see the faster solution by @panda-34.

Answer (score 3):

A simpler (and 3x faster than the accepted answer) way to use itertools product:

```
s = 'this is a string'
s2 = s.replace('%', '%%').replace(' ', '%s')
for i in itertools.product((' ', ''), repeat=s.count(' ')):
    print(s2 % i)
```

Comment: Very cool! I voted it up. I don't understand this part though `.replace('%', '%%')`. It seems redundant to me.

Comment: @tommy.carstensen - escape % characters if they happen to be in the original string to prepare for further format operation

Answer (score 2):

Well, it took me a little longer than I expected... this is actually tricker than I thought :)

The main idea:

The number of spaces when you split the string is the length or the split array - 1. In our example there are 3 spaces:

```
'this is a string'
     ^  ^ ^
```

We'll take a *binary representation* of all the options to have/not have either one of the spaces, so in our case it'll be:

```
000
001
011
100
101
...
```

and for each option we'll `generate` the sentence respectively, where 111 represents all 3 spaces: 'this is a string' and 000 represents no-space at all: 'thisisastring'

```
def binaries(n):
    res = []
    for x in range(n ** 2 - 1):
        tmp = bin(x)
        res.append(tmp.replace('0b', '').zfill(n))
    return res


def generate(arr, bins):
    res = []
    for bin in bins:
        tmp = arr[0]
        i = 1
        for digit in list(bin):
            if digit == '1':
                tmp = tmp + " " + arr[i]
            else:
                tmp = tmp + arr[i]
            i += 1
        res.append(tmp)
    return res


def combinations(string):
    s = string.split(' ')
    bins = binaries(len(s) - 1)
    res = generate(s, bins)
    return res


print combinations('this is a string')
# ['thisisastring', 'thisisa string', 'thisis astring', 'thisis a string', 'this isastring', 'this isa string', 'this is astring', 'this is a string']
```

**UPDATE:**
I now see that Amadan thought of the same idea - kudos for being quicker than me to think about! Great minds think alike ;)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is to do it recursively.

- Terminating condition: Schrödinger join of a single element list is that word.
- Recurring condition: say that L is the Schrödinger join of all the words but the first. Then the Schrödinger join of the list consists of all elements from L with the first word directly prepended, and all elements from L with the first word prepended with an intervening space.

(Assuming you are missing `thisis astring` by accident. If it is deliberately, I am sure I have no idea what the question is :P )

Another, non-recursive way you can do it is to enumerate all numbers from `0` to `2^(number of words - 1) - 1`, then use the binary representation of each number as a selector whether or not a space needs to be present. So, for example, the abovementioned `thisis astring` corresponds to `0b010`, for "nospace, space, nospace".

Comment: You're right, I did miss `thisis astring`.  Thanks for the catch.  I updated my question with this correction.  I'll take some time to internalize how to apply your comments Amadan.